# rsync fails and can't connect to host

Tags: macos, rsync

I am running a rsync script that is very simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync  -avz --delete <path> user@hostname:<dest path>
```

I use it everyday and works fine, today it seems I can't run it and I am not sure why. Biggest change to my system I made is update Java.

The behavior is it just looks like it hangs, and if i let it run long enough I get:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I am able to rsync from my host to my machine but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in my .bash_profile. I removed it and it seemed to work.

Odd thing is when I put it back it seems to still work